# Portfolio hover effect not working iphone & ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, iphone, hover

In my HTML template, portfolio hover effect not working iphone & ipad.I tried double tapping in ipad & iphone,but it does not works.
But in other devices its working fine.
I am newbie,I even dont know is it css or javascript related problem.
Do I need any custom code for iphone? or some code conflicting with this? 
TIA.

Comment: Hover is just that - when the **mouse/cursor** is over an object - and don't think its possible to hover on a phone or tablet

Comment: In android phones, you can tap over any html object and the related `:hover` effect in CSS works just fine. I know, it's not possible to `mouse hover` on a phone or tablet. My question is, when I see it on iPhone, it's not working like android (single tap triggering hover effect)

Answer (score 1):

iOS has no support for the prefix `:hover` but you can use `:focus` to do what you want.

Example - say we want this box to go green on hover.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: grey;
  }

div:hover, div:focus {
  background: green;
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Source: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/click-function-for-hover-states-on-touch-devices/)

Answer (score 0):

This is totally wired that even tapping is not working if you use CSS :hover effect on iPhone or iPad. In my case, I used this piece of JavaScript codes and :hover effect with transition works just fine :)

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) 
  || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) 
  || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $(".element").bind('touchstart', function(){
        //alert('touched');
    });
}
```